# Add mx.controls.Button to Flash Professional CS6 document

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, button, stage

I'm using Flash Professional CS6. It allows adding SWC files of Flex SDK. What I'm trying to do is adding the mx.controls.Button to stage. The code runs well, but the button doesn't appear on stage. Am I doing anything wrong in this code:

```
//f9 to open action editor
//in scene 1:
import mx.controls.Button;

var b:Button = new Button();
b.label = "My button";
b.width = 100;
b.height = 30; 
b.visible = true;

stage.addChild(b);
```

Comment: Try importing `fl.controls.Button`.

Comment: the flash ide says there is no such package 'fl.controls', also no 'flash.controls'

Comment: Go to Window->Components. Components dialog box appear. There click and drag `Button` under `User Interface` into your library

Comment: @Moorthy: but that isn't the mx.controls.Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[mx.controls]` [package](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/package-detail.html) contains controls for use in Flex / FlashBuilder. The `fl.controls` [package](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/package-detail.html) contains similar, but not necessarily equivalent, controls for use in the Flash IDE. If you just want to use a button, you should do what @Moorthy says and drag the button from the components library, then reference `fl.controls.Button`.

If you absolutely have to use Flex components in Flash, it is possible, you can do it like this:

> 1. Load the Flex swf into your flash
> 2. Wait until the loaded Flex component reaches frames 2 (all Flex swf's have 2 frames indeed)
> 3. Add the eventlistener (for the event defined in the flex) on the application property of the loaded object. This property is actually a
>      property of the SystemManager class. Remeber the SystemManager class
>      does not exist in Flash. It's a Flex thing.

- this procedure is taken from a nice blog on the subject, here: http://seeing-is-believing.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/flex-components-in-flash-example-with.html

It's worth saying that this makes sense for advanced Flex components, where you don't want to recode a lot of complex behaviour, but it is hard to imagine why you would need `mx.controls.Buttton` instead of `fl.controls.Button`, or your own `MovieClip`, as the behaviour is really quite common and straightforward.

Comment: i need to use mx controls because i have a bunch of classes coded in flex, now i need to use them for a flash project :)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I think the blog post linked above should cover that.